# Postfix filter incoming mail

Tags: postfix, filter

Currently I have a Postfix setup on a CentOS machine. It has multiple `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`.

There are multiple entries in `/etc/postfix/virtual` like:

```
user1@domain.tld user1, admin, supervisor@gmail.com
user2@domain.tld user2, supervisor@gmail.com
etc
```

It's all working fine, email is getting delivered where it should be, but here is the new requirement:

Supervisor does not want to be receiving copies of mail if the sender is info@domain.tld or info@anotherdomain.tld, etc. Rules can be different for each virtual alias. There might be multiple rules per single virtual alias.

So some basic rules:

- if user1@domain.tld receives an email, it should be delivered to
  user1, admin and supervisor@gmail.com (that's how it currently works
  and that what is defined in /etc/postfix/virtual)
- if user1@domain.tld receives an email from info@domain.tld, it should be delivered to user1 and admin, but not to supervisor@gmail.com

Basically this is required to reduce number of emails going to supervisor@gmail.com, but those emails should still reach other listed recipients.

What would be the best way to achieve that? Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Sounds to me like this is better solved with a filter at the receiving end.

Comment: Michael that might work, but the problem is that the supervisor is receiving too many emails and Gmail is rate-limiting that, so other, more important emails might get delayed. I can think of a workaround using an intermediate mailbox, but I was asked to build a feature (as described in my original question) into our proprietary mail account management software.